# Using SendKeys when Windows locks gets Access Denied

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a .NET Winform with a WebBrowser control that logs in to a website using username and password. The "submit" button is disabled until something is entered into the password textbox, so I can't use txt.SetAttribute() because it doesn't seem to enable the submit button. Using SendKeys.Send(password) works fine, and the submit button is enabled.

The problem is that when my computer locks, it seems the SendKeys command causes the following:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
```

At first I thought it would have to do with my account, but I am admin on the PC, and my session is still alive, it's just that the PC is locked.

I read [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?313632-quot-Sendkeys-quot-problem-while-computer-locked) that I could use SendMessage API function, so I tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(_formProcessName).FirstOrDefault();
if (p == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Login Error. Cannot find window process name: [{0}]", _formProcessName));
}
IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
SendMessage(h, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, _password);
```

...to no avail. No error, but it doesn't seem to send anything to the window, even though it does get the proper window handle.

My question is, how can I do a SendKeys() to a webbrowser control even when my pc is locked? Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You could stop your PC from being 'locked' by disabling the screen saver and auto standby stuff.  (If that is what is actually happening.)

Comment: That is an option. But this is a POC and the potential customer would not find that solution ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I decided to switch to [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). And it's much simpler!!

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    // Go to the home page
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("yourloginpageurl");

    var userNameField = driver.FindElementByName("userIdTextInput");
    userNameField.SendKeys("aaa");

    var passwordField = driver.FindElementByName("pwdIdTextInput");
    passwordField.SendKeys("bbb");

    var loginButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//form[@id='abc']/button");
    loginButton.Click();

}
```

It's that simple. It works fine when the PC is locked, so the main issue is solved with this. It's also easier to code. The [built-in wait objects](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) make it easier than the DocumentWait event for WebBrowser. If you're fighting issue after issue with WebBrowser control, I would recommend you to try Selenium. The only drawback I see so far is that it is a real instance of the browser you're using, so it's not built into your form where you can hide it if you want.